# How can I insert a resultset from psycopg2 into a SQL table using pyodbc?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, pyodbc

I have a psycopg connection:

```
conngre = psycopg2.connect("host='blah' port='blah' dbname='blah' user='blah' password='blah'")
conngre = conngre.cursor()

with open('exportgre', 'r') as selectexport:
    var1 = selectexport.read()
    conngre.execute(var1)
```

This calls a resultset that I want to then dump into SQL Server predefined table with connection:

```
sqlconn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=d;UID=blah;PWD=blah')
cursql = sqlconn.cursor()

with open('importsql', 'r') as selectexport:
    var2 = selectexport.read()
    cursql.execute(var2)
```

Is thier a way to pass the results from the first result set into an insert for the second resultset?

I have now ran the following code as a test in order to get this to work before using my actual sql:

```
import pyodbc

sqlconn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=d;UID=blah;PWD=blah')
cursql = sqlconn.cursor()

with cursql.execute("select * from blah.dbo.export_test"):

rows = cursql.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    cursql.execute('insert into TouchStar.dbo.export_test values (?)', (row[0]))
    print(row)
```

However it appears to just overwrite my data that is already in the table?

Do I need to append somehow?

Comment: Can you include an example of the SQL queries that you're running in the `exportgre` and `importsql` files? I'm not sure how the two files you're talking about refer to solving the problem. If I were trying to read from a PostreSQL and write to SQL Server, I'd just select the rows from PostgreSQL, loop over them, and insert what I needed into SQL Server without using any files. The PostgreSQL `fetchmany` method could be used to grab a certain number of rows at a time and generate a single insert using SQL Server `executemany`.

Comment: I cant really include the exact columns as company sensitive however the tables are like for like but will have a date extracted column at the start of the sql table.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Python dictionaries in the middle. First, select from PostgreSQL using RealDictCursor:

```
conngre = psycopg2.connect("host='blah' port='blah' dbname='blah' user='blah' password='blah'", cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
curgre = conngre.cursor()

sqlconn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=d;UID=blah;PWD=blah')
cursql = sqlconn.cursor()

with open('exportgre', 'r') as selectexport:
    var1 = selectexport.read()
    curgre.execute(var1)
    rows = curgre.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        cursql.execute('INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

For each SELECT statement in "selectexport", this will run the query, and loop over the rows. For each row, it will insert into the pyodbc cursor. You'll have to modify the insert statement to fit. Good luck!

Comment: Hi FlipperPA sorry for the delay I will work on this this afternoon. Will this create a SQL transaction per row? Or will it collate the full dictionary then execute all at once, my dataset is about 12,000 rows so can't afford 12,000 queries in sequence.

Comment: This would do 12000 insert queries. You could use `executemany` from pyodbc instead or `execute`.

Comment: Hi FlipperPA I have edited my question with code that I have tried to test pyodbc to pyodbc as my postgre connection is currently unavailable.